# Clear data of an application in a other application

Tags: android

i'm developing a android application, in this application i want to clear the data of an other application. how do you do this ? i already tried this.

[How to clear user data in your application](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically)

Comment: i don't think this is possible because the android system has the cache memory in a file that's readable only by your app

Answer (score 2):

Security on Android will not allow this.

Each application is sandboxed and access to data from other applications in this direct manner is restricted (and understandably so).

The only way to remove data from another application is if the target application stores it's data in a publicly accessible area (i.e) anywhere that is viewable via the file browser.

Comment: Probably best to ask on [Android Enthusiasts (Stack Exchange)](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Also try to avoid tackling different points via comments on the same question, it's difficult for people to find such questions in the search.